# Once html has been outputted using .html function in jQuery can it be targeted by jQuery again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am having a problem whereby a list of options is generated from some JSON data and then outputted to the DOM using .html function

```
          /* Function to get eventd based on subject areas */
          function checker() {
            var eventstext = ''; // Create eventstext
            $('#customise-1 input[type=checkbox]:checked').each( function(){
              var subject = $(this).val(); // Define subject
              var events = times[subject]; // Define events as subsect of JSON
              /* Loop through JSON data and add input details of each subject area */
              for (var i in events) {
                eventstext += '<div class="checkbox"><label><input class="times-check times-checker" type="checkbox" value="'+events[i].value+'">'+events[i].name+' : '+events[i].startTime+' to '+events[i].endTime+'</label></div>';//output checkboxes
              }
            });
            $('#sessiondisplay').html(eventstext);//output the data in this div
          }
          /* Happens on UG date selection */
          $('#ug-dateselector').change(function() {
            checker();
          });
          /* ALso happens when you select an option from the course list */
          $('#customise-1 input[type=checkbox]').click( function() {
            checker();
          });
```

This is outputted to the HTML document here

```
<div id="sessiondisplay">
                        </div>
                        <div class='checkbox times-none'>
                          <label>
                            <input type='checkbox' id='times-none' class="times-checker" value=''>
                            I don't want to attend any events
                          </label>
                        </div>
```

I am then trying to validate this by seeing if any objects with the .times-check have been checked.

```
  if ($('#times-none').is(':checked')) {
                    console.log('do not want to attend checked');
                    $($('#customiseDayTimesStatus')).removeClass('glyphicon-warning-sign');
                    $($('#customiseDayTimesStatus')).removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
                    $($('#customiseDayTimesStatus')).addClass('glyphicon-ok');
                    $($('#ug-dates-times-1')).removeClass('has-warning');
                    $($('#ug-dates-times-1')).removeClass('has-error');
                    $($('#ug-dates-times-1')).addClass('has-success');
                    $($('#ug-datesErrorMsg')).text('Done');
                    submittable = 0;
                  } else if ($('.times-check').is(':checked')) {
                    console.log('checked');
                    $($('#customiseDayTimesStatus')).removeClass('glyphicon-warning-sign');
                    $($('#customiseDayTimesStatus')).removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
                    $($('#customiseDayTimesStatus')).addClass('glyphicon-ok');
                    $($('#ug-dates-times-1')).removeClass('has-warning');
                    $($('#ug-dates-times-1')).removeClass('has-error');
                    $($('#ug-dates-times-1')).addClass('has-success');
                    $($('#ug-datesErrorMsg')).text('Done');
                  } else {
                    console.log('none checked');
                    $($('#customiseDayTimesStatus')).removeClass('glyphicon-warning-sign');
                    $($('#customiseDayTimesStatus')).removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
                    $($('#customiseDayTimesStatus')).addClass('glyphicon-remove');
                    $($('#ug-dates-times-1')).removeClass('has-warning');
                    $($('#ug-dates-times-1')).removeClass('has-success');
                    $($('#ug-dates-times-1')).addClass('has-error');
                  };
                });
```

I am adding the class 'times-check to the .html function however the validation function doesn't work, it works with the #times-none and finally the else statement.

I appreciate any help that can be given.

Thank you!

Comment: where are you firing the ' if ($('#times-none').is(':checked')) {' code?

Comment: You could shorten this code quite a bit by removing all the classes from a single element at the same time - `$('#ug-dates-times-1').removeClass('has-warning has-error has-success');`. In addition, you're syntax is incorrect - `$($(`

Comment: What do you mean by "the validation function doesn't work"?

Comment: The reason why the code isn't written like that is due to other members of the team been able to maintain the code and this surely wouldn't alter the validation function?

Comment: The if else statement, the else if isn't working unless I add a checkbox to the HTML page